# The letters do not look exactly in Edittext

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

The letters do not look exactly in Edittext
[click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLn1v.png)

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtsearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:hint="Ara"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:textColor="@color/siyah" />
```

border.xml :

android:shape="rectangle">

```
<corners
    android:radius="5dp"
    />
<solid android:color="#ffffff"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dip"
    android:color="#8f1d1d" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your `<EditText>` tag:

```
    android:gravity="bottom"
```

and add these:

```
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
```

This will position the text as follows:

[image]